# Calculate task status of an employee

Tags: tableau-api

I have two data sources namely "test1" and "test2". "test1" data source, task assigned to a particular employee. "test2" data source, task completed by an employee.

I would like to find an average,

task completed / total task assigned * 100 => 60%. Could you please help me out with this in performing calculations

[test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r01Cp.png)
[test2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r01Cp.png)

Thanks

Comment: Add meaningful data and both the images looks same... edit your question

Answer (score 0):

I assume every task completed is going to have a corresponding task assigned. You could take test1 data source and left join to test2 data source on name and task_id.  Then your calculated field is:

```
COUNTD([completed_task_id]) / COUNTD([assigned_task_id])
```

Substitute for however you end up naming your variables (right now they have the same name in both data sets: TaskId).

A second alternative is to union the data sets. Add a column for task_category (Assigned or Completed). Then make a calculated field:

```
COUNTD(IIF([task_category] = 'Completed',[task_id],NULL)
/
COUNTD(IIF([task_category] = 'Assigned',[task_id],NULL)
```

Comment: CountD() is an expensive operation. You’ll get better performance if you can rewrite a calculation or query to avoid needing CountD(). For example, the second calculation could just use Count() instead of CountD() if you can safely assume that each task is assigned or completed at most one time.